# BEncode.net urllist is null

Tags: c#, bencoding

I want get values from url-list from tracker-less torrent with just web seeds.

I writed this

```
     TorrentFile torrent = Bencode.DecodeTorrentFile("tr.torrent");
     BList urllist = (Blist)torrent["url-list"];
```

but this don't work because urllist is null. How to get url-list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode (BEncode) torrent files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067409/decode-bencode-torrent-files)

Comment: Posting the torrent file might help as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the debugger to investigate what's in the torrent variable after you do the following? There's probably tons on data in there if you set a breakpoint on your second line... The debugger is your friend.

```
TorrentFile torrent = Bencode.DecodeTorrentFile("tr.torrent");
```

Also, do you mean the trackers?
Look here: https://github.com/Krusen/BencodeNET

you might just want what's in

```
BList announceList = torrent["announce-list"];
```

Comment: I can get announce-list I want url-list. Here is screeen torrent structure http://i.imgur.com/Z4cPFhj.png url-list it list of web seeds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Web_seeding

Comment: So when you debug the torrent object, what's in there?

Comment: You keep posting that image. Is there a reason you aren't investigating the object in Visual Studio?

Comment: I writed this to read information from torrent TorrentFile torrent = Bencode.DecodeTorrentFile("tr.torrent");
            BString announce = (BString)torrent["announce"];
            object dat = (object)torrent["creation date"];
            object createdby = (object)torrent["created by"];
            object comment = (object)torrent["comment"];
            BDictionary ndata = torrent.Info;
            BString name = (BString)ndata["name"]; and this works to me but when I added BList urllist = (Blist)torrent["url-list"]; urllisit was null in debugger

Comment: You're kind of dodging around my question... Also, can you just post the torrent? It would make this hopefully a bit easier...